# Need to extract data from a df in a row

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like below:

```
Year Month
2003  06
2003  09
```

I want them to be extracted like below:

```
(('2003', '06'),('2003','09'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tuple(df.apply(lambda x: (x.Year, x.Month), axis=1).values)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tuple(tuple(vals) for vals in df.values)`